# How do I bind a list of tuples in jdbi?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbi

I have a mysql query in this format

```
SELECT * from xyz where (key1, key2) in (('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'));
```

I'm using jdbi to make this query. How do I bind the list of tuples in jdbi ?
I was trying to use something like this

```
List<String[]> query = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key: vars.keySet()){
  String[] entry = {key, vars.get(key)};
  query.add(entry);
}
List<String> result = getBasicQuery() + " WHERE (key, val) in (<query>)".bindList("query", query);
```

Getting this error on using bind this way

```
 No argument factory registered for '[Ljava.lang.String;@11fa461a' of type class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Answer (score 7):

It's actually quite easy to do this in JDBI3, but for some reason the solution isn't documented on [jdbi.org](http://jdbi.org/).

Here it is:

```
List<String> result = handle.createQuery(getBasicQuery() + " WHERE (key, val) in (<query>)")
    .bindMethodsList("query", query, List.of("getKey", "getValue"))
    .mapTo(String.class)
    .list();
```

Note that to use [`bindMethodsList()`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlStatement.html#bindMethodsList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.List-) you'll need to have your query objects defined as instances of a class with public methods (ie. getters). Something like this would work just fine:

```
class Query {
  String key;
  String value;

  Query(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can skip the getters by making the properties themselves public and using [`bindBeanList()`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlStatement.html#bindBeanList-java.lang.String-java.util.List-java.util.List-).

Comment: Both approach throws UnableToCreateStatementException error for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667296/jdbi-bindmethodslist-bindbeanlist-throws-unabletocreatestatementexception

Answer (score 1):

As @talon55 said, [bindBeanList](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlStatement.html#bindBeanList(java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.util.List)) method is an alternative:

```java
String QRY_STRING = "SELECT id FROM settlement_report WHERE (user_id, reference_id, has_type_id, record_type) IN (<conditions>)";

List<String> fieldsBean = Arrays.asList("userId", "referenceId", "hasTypeId", "recordType");

handle.createQuery(QRY_STRING)
.bindBeanList("conditions", records, fieldsBean);
```

Comment: This approach throws UnableToCreateStatementException error for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667296/jdbi-bindmethodslist-bindbeanlist-throws-unabletocreatestatementexception

Answer (score 1):

You can also use annotated interface methods for this query. Following mentioning my findings extending the example given by @talon55.

```
@RegisterRowMapper(xyzMapper.class)
public interface xyzDAO {

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE (key, value) in (<query>)")
    List<String> findAll(@BindMethodsList(value = "query", methodNames = {"getKey", "getValue"}) List<Query> query) throws UnableToExecuteStatementException;

}
```