# JDBI bindMethodsList()/bindBeanList() throws UnableToCreateStatementException

Tags: mysql, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I am trying to bind a list of tuples in JDBI:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class AuthorBooks {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    public long authorId;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    public long bookId;
}
```

Using bindMethodsList():

```
List<AuthorBooks> allAuthorBooks = Arrays.asList(new AuthorBooks(4394, 9977));
handler.createUpdate("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (author_id, book_id)"
                + " IS NOT IN (<allAuthorBooks>)")
      .bindMethodsList("allAuthorBooks", allAuthorBooks, List.of("getAuthorId, getBookId"))
      .execute();
```

Using bindBeanList():

```
List<AuthorBooks> allAuthorBooks = Arrays.asList(new AuthorBooks(4394, 9977));
handler.createUpdate("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (author_id, book_id)"
                + " IS NOT IN (<allAuthorBooks>)")
      .bindBeanList("allAuthorBooks", allAuthorBooks, List.of("authorId, bookId"))
      .execute();
```

Both approach throws error

> org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Unable to
> get getAuthorId, getBookId argument for AuthorBooks(authorId=4394,
> bookId=9977)

Answer (score 0):

For your attempt at `bindMethodsList()`, you need to actually add the `getAuthorId()` and `getBookId()` as public methods on your `AuthorBooks` class.

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is with your `bindBeanList()` implementation, but if you edit your question to include the specific error message, I'm happy to take a look.